# Is this a bug that list comprehenstion leak a variable name in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, list-comprehension

While learning coffeescript I found that this:

```
people = ("'#{name}'" for name in ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
```

compile to this

```
(function() {
  var name, people;

  people = (function() {
    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
    _ref = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      name = _ref[_i];
      _results.push("'" + name + "'");
    }
    return _results;
  })();

}).call(this);
```

Is this a bug that name can be accessed outside of list comprehensions? (I use coffeescript 1.4.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> **Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**
>
> The CoffeeScript compiler takes care to make sure that all of your variables are properly declared within lexical scope — you never need to write `var` yourself.
>
> [some example code]
>
> Notice how all of the variable declarations have been pushed up to the top of the closest scope, the first time they appear.

When you say:

```
for name ....
```

you're implicitly declaring the `name` variable and that will be hoisted to the top of the scope just like any other variable. A comprehension is not defined as a function or a new scope, the fact that it happens to be implemented using a `function` is just an implementation detail (which is simply meant to restrict the scope of the internal `_i`, `_len`, `_ref`, `_results` variables that CoffeeScript uses to implement the comprehension).

So you're not seeing a bug, you're just seeing the usual variable hoisting that happens in (Coffee|Java)Script.

Comment: It's weird, IMO it should put name as _name in that comprehenstion function. But it's the same as in Python.

Comment: But **all** variables are function-scoped and `name` is just another variable so it wouldn't make sense for a loop index to be treated specially. If I say `for(var i = 0...)` in JavaScript, `i` is hoisted to the top of the function and CoffeeScript is JavaScript so a CS loop should (and does) the same hoisting. I think you might be confusing implementation details with defined behavior.